# JavaScript reading objects in array

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous

Yesterday one of the members here on StackOverflow helped me with AJAX calls but now i have a problem.

Code is actually a loop that sends requests to multiple REST APIs and save results in array as objects.

Now the problem is that i cannot read objects from that array.

I would like to read objects and write new objects or update existing objects in that array.

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var items = [];
var types = [{
        suffix: '_ONOFF',
        handler: function(data, $el) {
            $el.prop('checked', data == 'ON');
        }
    },
    {
        suffix: '_URA',
        handler: function(data, $el) {
            $el.val(data);
        }
    },
    {
        suffix: '_MINUTA',
        handler: function(data, $el) {
            $el.val(data);
        }
    },
    {
        suffix: '_PO',
        handler: function(data, $el) {
            if (data == "ON") {
                $el.css('background', 'blue');
            } else if (data == "OFF") {
                $el.css('background', 'black');
            }
        }
    },
    {
        suffix: '_TO',
        handler: function(data, $el) {
            if (data == "ON") {
                $el.css('background', 'blue');
            } else {
                $el.css('background', 'black');
            }
        }
    },
    {
        suffix: '_SR',
        handler: function(data, $el) {
            if (data == "ON") {
                $el.css('background', 'blue');
            } else {
                $el.css('background', 'black');
            }
        }
    },
    {
        suffix: '_CE',
        handler: function(data, $el) {
            if (data == "ON") {
                $el.css('background', 'blue');
            } else {
                $el.css('background', 'black');
            }
        }
    },
    {
        suffix: '_PE',
        handler: function(data, $el) {
            if (data == "ON") {
                $el.css('background', 'blue');
            } else {
                $el.css('background', 'black');
            }
        }
    },
    {
        suffix: '_SO',
        handler: function(data, $el) {
            if (data == "ON") {
                $el.css('background', 'blue');
            } else {
                $el.css('background', 'black');
            }
        }
    },
    {
        suffix: '_NE',
        handler: function(data, $el) {
            if (data == "ON") {
                $el.css('background', 'blue');
            } else {
                $el.css('background', 'black');
            }
        }
    },
    {
        suffix: '_VALVE_SET',
        handler: function(data, $el) {
            $el.text(data);
        }
    },
];

for (var r = 1; r < 11; r++) {
    var result = {};
    types.forEach(function(type) {
        var key = `HVAC_VALVE01_SCHED${r}${type.suffix}`;
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: `http://192.168.1.111:8080/rest/items/${key}/state`
        }).done(function(data) {
            type.handler(data, $('.' + key));
            result[key] = data;
        });
    });
    items.push(result);
}
console.log(items);
console.log(items['HVAC_VALVE01_SCHED1_ONOFF']);
});
```

Comment: If you create a snippet with sample data, would be easier to help you with that :)

Comment: So what's the problem here?

Comment: Not sure if this is the problem, but Ajax calls are asynchronous to your `types.forEach` loop. Meaning that even if the loop is finished the calls are probably not. That's why the `console.log` returns an empty array: It is empty when the code reaches it. 
You have to work with callbacks as you already started in the `.done`: Use `console.log` only once all ajax calls have reached their `.done`.

Answer (score 0):

You see nothing in your `console.log`s because every AJAX call is **asynchronous**, and your code after the loop executes **before** the result of API call will be received. When I deal with multiple asynchronous operations, which you want to do at the same time, I usually use `Promise.all`, and I really love it. `Promise.all` accepts an array of promises and you can handle response inside `then` and `catch` blocks as with regular single promise. But notice, that `Promise.all` accepts an array, and in `then` block you will get an array too, an array of responses.

```
var apiCalls = [];
for (var r = 1; r < 11; r++) {
    var result = {};
    types.forEach(function(type) {
        var key = `HVAC_VALVE01_SCHED${r}${type.suffix}`;
        apiCalls.push(
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: `http://192.168.1.111:8080/rest/items/${key}/state`
            })
        )
    });
}
Promise.all(apiCalls)
    .then(function(response) {
        // "response" will contain the results of ALL you AJAX calls from "apiCalls" array
        // "response" will be an array of responses, so you have to merge this response with "items" array by yourself
        console.log(response); // here you can do all operations like "push" to existing array and so on
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
        console.error(err);
    });
```